# Is it possible to have a cumulative total of invoices based on customer name?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, worksheet, sumifs

I have a large Excel spreadsheet with three relevant columns.
They are `Invoice Number`, `Customer Name` and `Invoice Amount`. The Company Names are just free text, not a lookup, and it must stay that way. For example:

```
001, Company 001, 100.00
002, Company 002, 120.00
003, Company 003, 130.00
004, Company 001, 140.00
005, Company 158, 160.00
006, Company 003,  45.00
```

What I want is four columns, where column four is the cumulative invoice total for that customer, so my modified spreadsheet should be:

```
001, Company 001, 100.00, 100.00
002, Company 002, 120.00, 120.00
003, Company 003, 130.00, 130.00
004, Company 001, 140.00, 240.00
005, Company 158, 160.00, 160.00
006, Company 003,  45.00, 175.00
```

Can this be done in Excel without having to write VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `001` is in A2, in D2 please try:

```
=SUMIF(B$1:B2,B2,C$1:C2)
```

and copy down to suit.